# c++ string , pass by reference generates error from compiler

Tags: c++

```
void gp(vector<string>& res, string str, int l, int r, int n){
    if(l == n) {
        string right = string( n-r, ')');
        str += right;
        res.push_back(str);
        return;
    }
    gp(res, str+'(', l+1, r,n);
    if (l > r) {
        gp(res, str+')', l, r+1,n);
    }

}

vector<string> generateParenthesis(int n) {
    vector<string> res;
    gp(res, "", 0, 0, n);
    return res;

}
```

For this code 
if I change first line to

```
 void gp(vector<string>& res, string& str, int l, int r, int n){
```

> no matching function for call to
>   ‘Solution::gp(std::vector >&,
>   std::basic_string, int, int&, int&)’

My questions, why can't i pass by reference for this std::string?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string is actually a `const char *`, you are constructing an rvalue string from that `const char *` when calling the function, but your function needs an lvalue, since the reference is not const. This will work:

```
string mystring("");
gp(res, mystring, 0, 0, n);
```